# How come air units cause two drones even if they're in the home base?

Tags: alpha-centauri

In Alpha Centauri, with Social Engineering -5 Police states: two extra drones for each military unit away from territory. Why do I get two drones per air unit even if they're in the home base?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All offensive air units are considered out of territory no matter where they are. BUT this does not apply to defensive air units like interceptors (planes/choppers with the air superiority ability). See this article for more info: http://alphacentauri2.info/index.php?action=articles;sa=view;article=33

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, some unit types (apparently including air units) don't count as being home for the purposes of police duty. I cannot remember whether this applies to copters, but I seem to remember it applies to needle jets.

Comment: Sometimes, it applies to copters as well, but I haven't found a rule yet.